Unable to mount FUSE file system on tcp/ip server
I am building a simple distributed file system using FUSE and TCP/IP in C. I have some working server.c and client.c code that send requests and responses to each other. I also have a working FUSE filesystem code- fileystem.c which I have repeatedly tested by mounting on a new directory in my Ubuntu VM. Next step is to get the file system to run on the server so the client can make open, read, write, and list directory requests and receive responses in the form of output from the files or directories on the server.
My problem is that I put both the server.c and filesystem.c in the same file, fileServer.c, which I compile without errors. However, it seems the file system does not get mounted when i execute the following command although it works for the filesystem.c

./fileServer -f /home/anon/fuseFileSytem/dfs

I tried mounting explicitly after compiling with gcc using the line below, but got a /bin/sh/: 1: fileServer: not found output.

sudo mount -t fuse.fileServer ./fileServer /home/sena/finalProject_Sena_Senam/dfs

Can anyone please help me fix this? I need this fixed so i can work on remote connections between the client and server
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 30
//  included necessary libraries and headers //

#define NUM_SERVERS 1
#define BASE_PORT 8890
#define MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE 20000

// Server operations
int create_server_socket(int port);
void* server_thread(void* arg);
void* handle_client(void* arg);

// Function prototypes for integrating FUSE filesystem with server
// Call FUSE functions based on client request 
int open_file(const char* filename);
// int close_file(int fd);
int read_file(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi);
int read_directory(const char *path, void *buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi );
int write_tofile(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset);
int seek_file(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
int remove_file(const char* filename);
int cache_file(const char* filename);
int get_cache(const char* filename, void* buffer, size_t size);
int flush_cache();

// File system data structures
#define block_size 1024
typedef struct superblock {...} superblock;
typedef struct inode {...} inode;
typedef struct filetype {...} filetype;
filetype * root;
filetype file_array[200];
superblock spblock;

// File system operations
void initialize_superblock();
void tree_to_array(filetype * queue, int * front, int * rear, int * index);
int save_contents();
void initialize_root_directory();
filetype * filetype_from_path(char * path);
int find_free_inode();
int find_free_db();
void add_child(filetype * parent, filetype * child);
static int fsgetattr(const char *path, struct stat *statit);
static int fsmkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
int fsreaddir(const char *path, void *buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi );
int fscreate(const char * path, mode_t mode, struct fuse_file_info *fi);
int fsopen(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi);
int fsread(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi);
int fswrite(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi);
static int fsrelease(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi); 

// Error handling
void error(const char* message);

// Implemented file system integration functions
// Implemented FUSE file system functions


static struct fuse_operations fsoperations =
{
    .getattr=fsgetattr,     
    .mkdir=fsmkdir,         
    .readdir=fsreaddir,     
    .open=fsopen,           
    .read=fsread,           
    .create=fscreate,       
    .write=fswrite,         
    .release=fsrelease,     
};


void* server_thread(void* arg) {
    int port = *((int*) arg);
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    
    // Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    
    // Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    
    // Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        close(socket_desc);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    
    // Listen
    if (listen(socket_desc, 3) < 0) {
        perror("listen failed");
        close(socket_desc);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    
    // Accept and handle incoming connections
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    
    while (1) {
        // Accept connection from an incoming client
        client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if (client_sock < 0) {
            perror("accept failed");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Connection accepted on port %d\n", port);
        
        // Create a new thread to handle client request
        pthread_t client_thread;
        if (pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, handle_client, (void*)(intptr_t)client_sock) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create client thread");
            close(client_sock);
            continue;
        }
        
        // Detach the client thread
        pthread_detach(client_thread);
    }
    
    // Close server socket before exiting
    close(socket_desc);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


// Function to handle client request
void* handle_client(void* arg) {
    int client_sock = (intptr_t)arg;
    int read_size;
    char client_message[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
    
    // Receive a message from client
    while ((read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , sizeof(client_message) , 0)) > 0 ) {
        // Parse the received message (assuming format: "OPERATION filename")
        char operation[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
        char filename[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];

        if (sscanf(client_message, "%s %s", operation, filename) != 2) {
            // Invalid request format, send error response
            const char *error_message = "Invalid request format";
            if (write(client_sock, error_message, strlen(error_message)) < 0) {
                perror("Error writing to client socket");
            }
            close(client_sock);
            return NULL;
        }

        if (strcmp(operation, "OPEN") == 0) {
            // Handle open file request
            int file_descriptor = open_file(filename);

            if (file_descriptor < 0) {
                // Send error message indicating file not found or other error
                const char *error_message = "File not found or error occurred";
                if (write(client_sock, error_message, strlen(error_message)) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to client socket");
                }
            } else {
                // Send success message and file descriptor
                if (write(client_sock, &file_descriptor, sizeof(file_descriptor)) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to client socket");
                    close(client_sock);
                    // close_file(file_descriptor); // Close the file before exiting
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        } else if (strcmp(operation, "READ") == 0) {
            // Handle read file request
            // Read file contents and send them to the client
            char buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
            ssize_t bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = read_file(filename, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL)) > 0) {
                // Send file contents to client
                if (write(client_sock, buffer, bytes_read) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to client socket");
                    close(client_sock);
                    // close_file(file_descriptor); // Close the file before exiting
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            if (bytes_read < 0) {
                // Error reading file, send error message to client
                const char *error_message = "Error reading file";
                if (write(client_sock, error_message, strlen(error_message)) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to client socket");
                }
            }
        } else if (strcmp(operation, "CLOSE") == 0) {
            // Handle close file request
            int file_descriptor;
            if (sscanf(client_message, "%s %d", operation, &file_descriptor) != 2) {
                const char *error_message = "Invalid request format";
                if (write(client_sock, error_message, strlen(error_message)) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to client socket");
                }
                close(client_sock);
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        
    }
    
    if(read_size == 0) {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else if(read_size < 0) {
        perror("recv failed");
    }
    
    close(client_sock); // Close the client socket
    
    return NULL;
}


void initialize_filesystem() {
    FILE *fd = fopen("file_structure.bin", "rb");
    if (fd) {
        printf("LOADING\n");
        fread(&file_array, sizeof(filetype)*31, 1, fd);

        int child_startindex = 1;
        file_array[0].parent = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            file_array[i].num_children = 0;
            file_array[i].children = NULL;
            for (int j = child_startindex; j < child_startindex + 5; j++) {
                if (file_array[j].valid) {
                    add_child(&file_array[i], &file_array[j]);
                }
            }
            child_startindex += 5;
        }

        root = &file_array[0];

        FILE *fd1 = fopen("super.bin", "rb");
        fread(&spblock, sizeof(superblock), 1, fd1);
    } else {
        initialize_superblock();
        initialize_root_directory();
    }
}

Main function:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize the file system
    initialize_filesystem();

    // Check if DFS tree initialization failed
    if (root == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize DFS tree\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create and start server threads
    pthread_t server_threads[NUM_SERVERS];
    int ports[NUM_SERVERS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SERVERS; i++) {
        ports[i] = BASE_PORT + i;
        if (pthread_create(&server_threads[i], NULL, server_thread, (void*)&ports[i]) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create server thread");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Server %d started on port %d\n", i+1, ports[i]);
    }

    // Wait for server threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SERVERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(server_threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // Start the FUSE filesystem after the server threads are created
    struct fuse_args args = FUSE_ARGS_INIT(argc, argv);
    int fuse_ret = fuse_main(args.argc, args.argv, &fsoperations, NULL);
    fuse_opt_free_args(&args);

    if (fuse_ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fuse filesystem exited with error code %d\n", fuse_ret);
        return fuse_ret;
    }

    return 0;
}


We're going to need more technical detail about the code involved. This is just some after-action report. How did you build the executable? What did you build it into?

Hello, I have updated the question with my code without the full implementation of my FUSE functions to reduce the length. I compile using gcc  in ubuntu 22. I need to know if my approach to integrating the fuse filesystem with my server is correct and if so, how do i mount?
Compile: gcc fileServer.c -o fileServer pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs
Run server and mount FS: ./fileServer -f /home/anon/fuseFileSytem/dfs
Thanks

Where in your code do you mount the file system (e.g. call something like fuse_main)?

I just realised i left that out. I added it and it works, but looks like there's a tradeoff between the mounting and the server creation. When I initialize the server before calling fuse_main in my main function, the file system isn't mounted. However, when I called fuse_main before creating the server, the file system gets mounted but the server isn't created. Not sure why. I have updated the main function in my question's code section accordingly

In your latest edit you're waiting for the server threads to finish before you mount the file system.  You need to move the mount so it's after the threads start but before they finish.
